# How to reduce response time while data display , which is parsed by SOAP service

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection, grand-central-dispatch, nsurlsession

- I am trying to Parse SOAP data [using NSURLConnection, as I am not getting to use NSURLSession]
- and trying to display that on multiple UILabels

**Issue is - when printing response data on Console it is printed quickly, but It is taking too much time (50-60 sec) to display on labels.**

Please suggest me any possible way to display data quickly, Here is my code

```
#pragma mark - post data function
-(void)getEmployeeData{
    //Renewed CODE
    loginData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]init];
    NSString *methodName = @"Get_Data";

    //SOAP Start
    [connectionManagerObject getStartSoapData:loginData :methodName];

    //SOAP Body
    NSString *passedUserID = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"StoredUserID"];
    //    NSLog(@"passed UserID : %@",passedUserID);
    NSString *passedPassword = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"StoredPassword"];
    //    NSLog(@"passed Password : %@",passedPassword);

    NSString *userIdValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<EMP_NAME>%@</EMP_NAME>",passedUserID];
    NSString *passwordValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<EMP_PASSWORD>%@</EMP_PASSWORD>",passedPassword];
    [loginData appendData:[userIdValue dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [loginData appendData:[passwordValue dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    //SOAP End
    [connectionManagerObject getEndSoapData:loginData :methodName];

    //SOAP Request
    [connectionManagerObject getRequest:loginData :request :[NSURL URLWithString:HOST_URL] :methodName];

    //Start connection
    [self startConnectionWithRequest:request];
}

#pragma mark - Start Connection
-(void)startConnectionWithRequest:(NSMutableURLRequest *)URLRequest
{
    loginConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:URLRequest delegate:self startImmediately:YES];

    if (loginConnection)
    {
        //        NSLog(@" \n\n Successfully connected with server !!! ");
    }
    else
    {
        //        NSLog(@" \n\n Connection Not Established !!! ");
    }

    [loginConnection start];
}

#pragma mark - Connection Delegate

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [loginData setLength:0];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(nonnull NSData *)data
{
    [loginData appendData:data];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Warning !" message:@"Please Check your internet connection" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];
    [alertController addAction:ok];
    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];

}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{

    NSString *responseString = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithData:loginData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    responseString = [responseString substringFromIndex:[responseString rangeOfString:@"<Get_DataResult>"].location + [@"<Get_DataResult>" length]];
    responseString = [responseString substringToIndex:[responseString rangeOfString:@"</Get_DataResult>"].location];

    //    NSLog(@"Response string : %@",responseString);


    if ([responseString containsString:@"^"])
    {
        [self displayProfileData:responseString];
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Warning !" message:@"Please Check your login credentials" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

        UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];
        [alertController addAction:ok];
        [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];

        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];

    }


}


#pragma mark - Display data function

-(void)displayProfileData:(NSString *)storedEmployeeResponse
{
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(start) toTarget:self withObject:nil];

    //GCD CODE
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{


    // do my time consuming task and everytime it wants to update the UI,
    // it should dispatch that back to the main queue, e.g.

    NSArray *passEmpDataArray = [[NSArray alloc]init];
    passEmpDataArray = [storedEmployeeResponse componentsSeparatedByString:@"^"];

    NSString *empCodeStr = [passEmpDataArray objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *empNameStr = [passEmpDataArray objectAtIndex:1];
    NSString *empDeptStr = [passEmpDataArray objectAtIndex:3];
    NSString *empDesgStr = [passEmpDataArray objectAtIndex:5];
    NSString *empGenderStr = [passEmpDataArray objectAtIndex:4];
    NSString *empDojStr = [passEmpDataArray objectAtIndex:6];
    NSString *empDobStr = [passEmpDataArray objectAtIndex:7];
    NSString *empEmailStr = [passEmpDataArray objectAtIndex:9];
    NSString *empMobileStr = [passEmpDataArray objectAtIndex:8];



    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    // update the UI accordingly

    _empCodeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Emp Code    %@",empCodeStr];
    _empNameLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Emp Name   %@",empNameStr];
    _empDeptLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Emp Dept    %@",empDeptStr];
    _empDesgLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Emp Desg   %@",empDesgStr];
    _empGenderLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Gender         %@",empGenderStr];
    _empDojLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"DOJ              %@",empDojStr];
    _empDobLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"DOB              %@",empDobStr];
    _empEmailIdLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Email ID        %@",empEmailStr];
    _empMobileNo.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Mobile No     %@",empMobileStr];


    NSString *tempUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:Image_URL,empCodeStr];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:tempUrl];
    loginData = [NSMutableData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    _profilePic.image = [UIImage imageWithData:loginData];

    [self stop];

    });

    });

}

#pragma mark - post data function
-(void)getEmployeeData
{

    //Renewed CODE
    loginData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]init];
    NSString *methodName = @"Get_Data";

    //SOAP Start
    [connectionManagerObject getStartSoapData:loginData :methodName];

    //SOAP Body
    NSString *passedUserID = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"StoredUserID"];
    //    NSLog(@"passed UserID : %@",passedUserID);
    NSString *passedPassword = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"StoredPassword"];
    //    NSLog(@"passed Password : %@",passedPassword);

    NSString *userIdValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<EMP_NAME>%@</EMP_NAME>",passedUserID];
    NSString *passwordValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<EMP_PASSWORD>%@</EMP_PASSWORD>",passedPassword];
    [loginData appendData:[userIdValue dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [loginData appendData:[passwordValue dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    //SOAP End
    [connectionManagerObject getEndSoapData:loginData :methodName];

    //SOAP Request
    [connectionManagerObject getRequest:loginData :request :[NSURL URLWithString:HOST_URL] :methodName];

    //Start connection
    [self startConnectionWithRequest:request];
}
#pragma mark - Start Connection
-(void)startConnectionWithRequest:(NSMutableURLRequest *)URLRequest
{
    loginConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:URLRequest delegate:self startImmediately:YES];

    if (loginConnection)
    {
        //        NSLog(@" \n\n Successfully connected with server !!! ");
    }
    else
    {
        //        NSLog(@" \n\n Connection Not Established !!! ");
    }

    [loginConnection start];
}

#pragma mark - Connection Delegate

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [loginData setLength:0];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(nonnull NSData *)data
{
    [loginData appendData:data];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Warning !" message:@"Please Check your internet connection" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];
    [alertController addAction:ok];
    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];

}
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{

    NSString *responseString = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithData:loginData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    responseString = [responseString substringFromIndex:[responseString rangeOfString:@"<Get_DataResult>"].location + [@"<Get_DataResult>" length]];
    responseString = [responseString substringToIndex:[responseString rangeOfString:@"</Get_DataResult>"].location];

    //    NSLog(@"Response string : %@",responseString);


    if ([responseString containsString:@"^"])
    {
        [self displayProfileData:responseString];
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Warning !" message:@"Please Check your login credentials" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

        UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];
        [alertController addAction:ok];
        [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];

        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];

    }


}


#pragma mark - Display data function
-(void)displayProfileData:(NSString *)storedEmployeeResponse
{
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(start) toTarget:self withObject:nil];

    //GCD CODE
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{


    // do my time consuming task and everytime it wants to update the UI,
    // it should dispatch that back to the main queue, e.g.

    NSArray *passEmpDataArray = [[NSArray alloc]init];
    passEmpDataArray = [storedEmployeeResponse componentsSeparatedByString:@"^"];

    NSString *empCodeStr = [passEmpDataArray objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *empNameStr = [passEmpDataArray objectAtIndex:1];
    NSString *empDeptStr = [passEmpDataArray objectAtIndex:3];
    NSString *empDesgStr = [passEmpDataArray objectAtIndex:5];
    NSString *empGenderStr = [passEmpDataArray objectAtIndex:4];
    NSString *empDojStr = [passEmpDataArray objectAtIndex:6];
    NSString *empDobStr = [passEmpDataArray objectAtIndex:7];
    NSString *empEmailStr = [passEmpDataArray objectAtIndex:9];
    NSString *empMobileStr = [passEmpDataArray objectAtIndex:8];



    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    // update the UI accordingly

    _empCodeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Emp Code    %@",empCodeStr];
    _empNameLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Emp Name   %@",empNameStr];
    _empDeptLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Emp Dept    %@",empDeptStr];
    _empDesgLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Emp Desg   %@",empDesgStr];
    _empGenderLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Gender         %@",empGenderStr];
    _empDojLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"DOJ              %@",empDojStr];
    _empDobLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"DOB              %@",empDobStr];
    _empEmailIdLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Email ID        %@",empEmailStr];
    _empMobileNo.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Mobile No     %@",empMobileStr];


    NSString *tempUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:Image_URL,empCodeStr];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:tempUrl];
    loginData = [NSMutableData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    _profilePic.image = [UIImage imageWithData:loginData];

    [self stop];

    });

    });

}
```

Comment: I would suggest you to execute your function displayProfileData on main thread. but for image _profilePic.image use SDWebImageLibrary for lazy loading.

Comment: That's almost certainly the problem.  Making UI changes on any thread other than the main thread is completely unsupported.  In the rare instances where it doesn't crash outright, the UI doesn't get updated until code running on the main thread causes a UI change.

Comment: It got solved , it was taking time because of lazy image loading. thanks @Dev_Tandel

Comment: Happy Coding...